# Auto-populate a cloumn based on created by

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created a timesheet tool.
I'm allowing users to create new records in a list and also displaying that list of records that are created.

I don't want people to choose their name and supervisor name from the list.
I use "created by" as the owner of the record.
But I am not able to auto-assign supervisor name based on "created by" column.

For example,

if a record created by user X, the system automatically assigns the user Y as a supervisor.

if a record created by user A, the system automatically assigns the user B as a supervisor.

Since I use "Created By" column which has type "Person or Group", I am not able to auto-calculate based on this information.

Does anyone know?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to auto populate the Supervisor column (which is a people column) based on the created by column. In SharePoint Online, I will suggest you to use Power Automate to create a flow for auto-populating. Still we need the number of combinations about created by and supervisor is limited to a small number. Thus we can use a Switch action in flow to handle this part.

For updating people column things will be a bit complicated as we cannot use the email address directly for updating. We need to use the claim and that is the way SharePoint identifies it is a person.

Example: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/79376/approval-flow-with-multiple-approvers-save-all-app.html.

About using Switch case: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-with-more-than-5-conditions/td-p/30214

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in another answer Power Automate would be the way to go.

If you have the Manager information already populated as part of the Users Profile in 365 you could achieve this in 4 steps.

1. You can set a trigger to occur on Item Creation
2. Get the person creating the item's profile information
3. Use the mail output of the previous step to get the Manager
4. Update the original item with the Manager from the previous step.

[image]